# how to feed data from binary string ubyte vector of flatbuffer in python?

Tags: python, flatbuffers

I have following table with mentioned fields:

```
table Blob {
name        : string;
size        : ulong;
data        : [ubyte];
}
```

And following API's are generated

```
def BlobStart(builder): builder.StartObject(3)
def BlobAddName(builder, name): builder.PrependUOffsetTRelativeSlot(0, flatbuffers.number_types.UOffsetTFlags.py_type(name), 0)
def BlobAddSize(builder, size): builder.PrependUint64Slot(1, size, 0)
def BlobAddData(builder, data): builder.PrependUOffsetTRelativeSlot(2, flatbuffers.number_types.UOffsetTFlags.py_type(data), 0)
def BlobStartDataVector(builder, numElems): return builder.StartVector(1, numElems, 1)
def BlobEnd(builder): return builder.EndObject()
```

And addition to that I have a binary stirng `bin_data`, now I want to fill that data to `data` vector of Blob. How to do that ?

I have following piece of code:

```
blobName = builder.CreateString(blob_name)

Blob.BlobStartDataVector(builder, len(blob_data))
for i in reversed(range(0, len(blob_data))):
    builder.PrependByte(blob_data[i])   #Error here
blob_bin_data = builder.EndVector(len(blob_data))

Blob.BlobStart(builder)
Blob.BlobAddName(builder, blobName)
Blob.BlobAddSize(builder, 30) #for example size is 30
Blob.BlobAddData(builder, blob_bin_data)
binaryBlob = BlobEnd(builder)
```

With above snippet of code, I get following error:

```
    builder.PrependByte(blob_data[i])
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/flatbuffers/builder.py", line 544, in PrependByte
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/flatbuffers/builder.py", line 472, in Prepend
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/flatbuffers/builder.py", line 627, in Place
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/flatbuffers/number_types.py", line 148, in enforce_number
TypeError: bad number  for type uint8
```

**Seeking for help, how to feed binary data to array of byte ?**

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `blob_data` object does not actually contain bytes. You could debug it to print the byte in that loop and make sure it fits [0, 255]

Comment: I see all values lies in [0,255].

Comment: I see when I convert bin_data to arr=bytearray(bin_data) and iterate over arr it works, but I want to copy the binary data to `data`, how to do that ?